# Reproduce S-plus result in R

Tags: r, random, random-seed, s, s-plus

I have an old S-plus script, and I would like to reproduce the results in R. The only issue I'm having is the random seed. I know they use different algorithms for the pseudo-random number generation. In the S-plus file the seed was set using:

```
set.seed(337)
```

The relevant information I could find is

[S-plus set seed](http://www.uni-muenster.de/ZIV.BennoSueselbeck/s-html/helpfiles/set.seed.html)

[R set seed](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Random.html)

From this documentation it looks like S-plus used the "Super-duper" algorithm for pseudo-random number generation. R has this option, but it says it takes in 2 integers, while S-plus only requires 1 integer between 0 and 1000. Furthermore the R doc says

```
The two seeds are the Tausworthe and congruence long integers, respectively. 
A one-to-one mapping to S's .Random.seed[1:12] is possible but we will not
publish one, not least as this generator is not exactly the same as that in
recent versions of S-PLUS.
```

I'm not quite sure what this means. So does anyone know if it would be possible to replicate results?

An [old post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/1999-May/019139.html) on the R mailing list tries to get same results in S/R/Splus.

Comment: If all else fails you could write out the random digits S-plus uses to a file and read those into R and use them directly.  Obviously not the ideal approach but if you're strapped for time and all else fails...

Comment: It means that R cannot exactly reproduce S’ random number generator output even if you provided the exact same seed. As an alternative to @Dason’s suggestion you could try reimplementing S’ Super-duper generator in R. This would need to be carefully tested, though. For a single replication, Dason’s suggestion is simpler.

Comment: … it should be noted, additionally, that robust results should not/do not rely on identical replication to result in equal results. Your mileage may vary, but this is generally a reason to doubt the results in the first place.